# MVVM WPF Add new item to the DataGrid from Textboxes which are bound to the nested properties of the Model class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I am new to WPF and also the MVVM pattern, I tried to create a simple WPF project to query a database of I-Shape Steel Profiles and show it to the user through the DataGrid. After I have successfully done it, I am now moving to the next part: Letting the user to add new steel profiles to the DataGrid by filling out a set of TextBoxes.

**Model**

```
namespace SectionGuardWPF.MVVM.Model
{
    public class IProfileModel : ObservableObject
    {
        #region Private Fields
        public short _recno;
        public string _name;
        public string _staadName;
        public double _ax;
        public double _d;
        public double _bf;
        public double _tf;
        public double _tw;
        public double _iz;
        public double _ix;
        public double _ct;
        public double _iy;
        public double _zx;
        public double _zy;
        #endregion

        #region Public Properties
        /// <summary>
        /// Properties are given NotifyPropertyChanged method to allow for a change in property to be notified
        /// </summary>

        public short RECNO
        {
            get { return _recno; }
            set
            {
                _recno = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
...
// Repeated for the other fields
```

**ObservableObject: Base class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`**

```
namespace SectionGuardWPF.Core
{
    public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Raised when a property on this object has a new value.
        /// </summary>
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// Raises this object's PropertyChanged event.
        /// </summary>
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null) // If you use the CallerMemberName attribute, calls to the NotifyPropertyChanged method don't have to specify the property name as a string argument
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

**RelayCommand**

```
namespace SectionGuardWPF.Core
{
    class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private Action<object> _execute;
        private Func<object, bool> _canExecute;

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object,bool> canExecute=null)
        {
            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
        }
        
        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute(parameter);
        }
    }
}
```

**View Model**

```
namespace SectionGuardWPF.MVVM.ViewModel
{
    public class IProfilesViewModel:ObservableObject
    {
        #region Private Fields
        private readonly string _connectionString = //Hidden
        private ObservableCollection<IProfileModel> _iProfiles;
        private ICommand _getIProfilesCommand;
        private ICommand _addNewIProfileCommand;
        private IProfileModel _iProfile = new IProfileModel();
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public IProfilesViewModel()
        {
            // Set default Profile Database for the DataGrid upon View instantiation
            IProfiles = GetIProfiles();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Public Properties and Commands
        /// <summary>
        /// Public properties of the IProfilesViewModel Class (used for view binding with IProfilesSubView)
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableCollection<IProfileModel> IProfiles
        {
            get { return _iProfiles; }
            set
            {
                _iProfiles = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public IProfileModel IProfile
        {
            get { return _iProfile; }
            set
            {
                _iProfile = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public ICommand GetIProfilesCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_getIProfilesCommand == null)
                {
                    _getIProfilesCommand = new RelayCommand(
                        param => GetIProfiles()
                    );
                }
                return _getIProfilesCommand;
            }
        }
        public ICommand AddNewIProfileCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_addNewIProfileCommand == null)
                {
                    _addNewIProfileCommand = new RelayCommand(
                        param => AddNewIProfile()
                    );
                }
                return _addNewIProfileCommand;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Private Methods
        private ObservableCollection<IProfileModel> GetIProfiles()
        {
            TableDataProvider tableDataProvider = new TableDataProvider(_connectionString);
            tableDataProvider.QueryString = "SELECT * FROM [I Shape]";

            IEnumerable<IProfileModel> iProfiles = tableDataProvider.Query<IProfileModel>();
            ObservableCollection<IProfileModel> iProfileObsvCol = new ObservableCollection<IProfileModel>(iProfiles);
            return iProfileObsvCol;
        }

        private void AddNewIProfile()
        {
            IProfiles.Add(
                new IProfileModel
                {
                    RECNO = IProfile.RECNO,
                    Name = IProfile.Name,
                    StaadName = IProfile.StaadName,
                    AX = IProfile.AX,
                    D = IProfile.D,
                    Bf = IProfile.Bf,
                    Tf = IProfile.Tf,
                    Tw = IProfile.Tw,
                    Ix = IProfile.Ix,
                    Iy = IProfile.Iy,
                    Iz = IProfile.Iz,
                    Ct = IProfile.Ct,
                    Zx = IProfile.Zx,
                    Zy = IProfile.Zy
                }
                );
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<UserControl x:Class="SectionGuardWPF.MVVM.View.IProfilesSubView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SectionGuardWPF.MVVM.View"
             xmlns:viewModel= "clr-namespace:SectionGuardWPF.MVVM.ViewModel"
             xmlns:view="clr-namespace:SectionGuardWPF.MVVM.View"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="580" d:DesignWidth="1300">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewModel:IProfilesViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="620"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <DataGrid x:Name="ProfilesDataGrid"
                      x:FieldModifier="public"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding IProfiles, Mode=TwoWay}">

        </DataGrid>

        <Border Grid.Column="1"
                CornerRadius="20"
                Background ="White"
                Margin="10">
            <Grid Margin="10">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="150"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Text="I-Profiles Data Viewer"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Margin="20,0,0,0"
                   Foreground="Black"
                   FontSize="22"/>

                <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Text="RECNO"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               Margin="20,0,0,0"
                               Foreground="#1A80FA"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               Grid.Row="0"
                               FontSize="14"/>

                    <TextBox x:Name="RECNOTextBox"
                             Margin="0,0,20,0"
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                             Style="{StaticResource ParameterTextbox}"
                             Grid.Column="0"
                             Grid.Row="0"
                             Text="{Binding IProfile.RECNO, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

                    <TextBlock Text="Name"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               Margin="20,0,0,0"
                               Foreground="#1A80FA"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               Grid.Row="1"
                               FontSize="14"/>

                    <TextBox x:Name="NameTextBox"
                             Margin="0,0,20,0"
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                             Style="{StaticResource ParameterTextbox}"
                             Grid.Column="0"
                             Grid.Row="1"
                             Text="{Binding IProfile.Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

                    <TextBlock Text="StaadName"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               Margin="20,0,0,0"
                               Foreground="#1A80FA"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               Grid.Row="2"
                               FontSize="14"/>

                    <TextBox x:Name="StaadNameTextBox"
                             Margin="0,0,20,0"
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                             Style="{StaticResource ParameterTextbox}"
                             Grid.Column="0"
                             Grid.Row="2"
                             Text="{Binding IProfile.StaadName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

                    <TextBlock Text="AX"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               Margin="20,0,0,0"
                               Foreground="#1A80FA"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               Grid.Row="3"
                               FontSize="18"/>

                    <TextBox x:Name="AXTextBox"
                             Margin="0,0,20,0"
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                             Style="{StaticResource ParameterTextbox}"
                             Grid.Column="0"
                             Grid.Row="3"
                             Text="{Binding IProfile.AX, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

                    <TextBlock Text="D"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               Margin="20,0,0,0"
                               Foreground="#1A80FA"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               Grid.Row="4"
                               FontSize="18"/>

                    <TextBox x:Name="DTextBox"
                             Margin="0,0,20,0"
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                             Style="{StaticResource ParameterTextbox}"
                             Grid.Column="0"
                             Grid.Row="4"
                             Text="{Binding IProfile.D, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

                    <TextBlock Text="Bf"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               Margin="20,0,0,0"
                               Foreground="#1A80FA"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               Grid.Row="5"
                               FontSize="18"/>

                    <TextBox x:Name="BfTextBox"
                             Margin="0,0,20,0"
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                             Style="{StaticResource ParameterTextbox}"
                             Grid.Column="0"
                             Grid.Row="5"
                             Text="{Binding IProfile.Bf, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

                    <TextBlock Text="Tf"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               Margin="20,0,0,0"
                               Foreground="#1A80FA"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               Grid.Row="6"
                               FontSize="18"/>

                    <TextBox x:Name="TfTextBox"
                             Margin="0,0,20,0"
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                             Style="{StaticResource ParameterTextbox}"
                             Grid.Column="0"
                             Grid.Row="6"
                             Text="{Binding IProfile.Tf, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

                    <TextBlock Text="Tw"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               Margin="20,0,0,0"
                               Foreground="#1A80FA"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               Grid.Row="0"
                               FontSize="18"/>

                    <TextBox x:Name="TwTextBox"
                             Margin="0,0,20,0"
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                             Style="{StaticResource ParameterTextbox}"
                             Grid.Column="1"
                             Grid.Row="0"
                             Text="{Binding IProfile.Tw, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

                    <TextBlock Text="Ix"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               Margin="20,0,0,0"
                               Foreground="#1A80FA"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               Grid.Row="1"
                               FontSize="18"/>

                    <TextBox x:Name="IxTextBox"
                             Margin="0,0,20,0"
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                             Style="{StaticResource ParameterTextbox}"
                             Grid.Column="1"
                             Grid.Row="1"
                             Text="{Binding IProfile.Ix, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

                    <TextBlock Text="Iy"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               Margin="20,0,0,0"
                               Foreground="#1A80FA"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               Grid.Row="2"
                               FontSize="18"/>

                    <TextBox x:Name="IyTextBox"
                             Margin="0,0,20,0"
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                             Style="{StaticResource ParameterTextbox}"
                             Grid.Column="1"
                             Grid.Row="2"
                             Text="{Binding IProfile.Iy, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

                    <TextBlock Text="Iz"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               Margin="20,0,0,0"
                               Foreground="#1A80FA"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               Grid.Row="3"
                               FontSize="18"/>

                    <TextBox x:Name="IzTextBox"
                             Margin="0,0,20,0"
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                             Style="{StaticResource ParameterTextbox}"
                             Grid.Column="1"
                             Grid.Row="3"
                             Text="{Binding IProfile.Iz, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

                    <TextBlock Text="Ct"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               Margin="20,0,0,0"
                               Foreground="#1A80FA"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               Grid.Row="4"
                               FontSize="18"/>

                    <TextBox x:Name="CtTextBox"
                             Margin="0,0,20,0"
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                             Style="{StaticResource ParameterTextbox}"
                             Grid.Column="1"
                             Grid.Row="4"
                             Text="{Binding IProfile.Ct, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

                    <TextBlock Text="Zx"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               Margin="20,0,0,0"
                               Foreground="#1A80FA"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               Grid.Row="5"
                               FontSize="18"/>

                    <TextBox x:Name="ZxTextBox"
                             Margin="0,0,20,0"
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                             Style="{StaticResource ParameterTextbox}"
                             Grid.Column="1"
                             Grid.Row="5"
                             Text="{Binding IProfile.Zx, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

                    <TextBlock Text="Zy"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               Margin="20,0,0,0"
                               Foreground="#1A80FA"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               Grid.Row="6"
                               FontSize="18"/>

                    <TextBox x:Name="ZyTextBox"
                             Margin="0,0,20,0"
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                             Style="{StaticResource ParameterTextbox}"
                             Grid.Column="1"
                             Grid.Row="6"
                             Text="{Binding IProfile.Zy, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </Grid>

                <StackPanel Grid.Row="2"
                            Orientation="Horizontal">

                    <Button x:Name="AddButton"
                            Style="{StaticResource AddButton}"
                            Content="Add"
                            Background="#28C941"
                            Height="50"
                            Width="150"
                            Margin="85,0,0,0"
                            Command="{Binding AddNewIProfileCommand}"/>
                    <Button x:Name="EditButton"
                            Style="{StaticResource AddButton}"
                            Content="Edit"
                            Background="#FFBD2E"
                            Height="50"
                            Width="150"
                            Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
                    <Button x:Name="DeleteButton"
                            Style="{StaticResource AddButton}"
                            Content="Delete"
                            Background="#FF6059"
                            Height="50"
                            Width="150"
                            Margin="20,0,0,0"/>

                </StackPanel>
                
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

My Model class is a class called the `IProfileModel` that represents the I-Shape Profiles, I have made so that it inherits from the `ObservableObject` class so that it can use the NotifyPropertyChanged methods and I have made so that the properties of the Model class has implemented the `OnPropertyChanged()` Method.

In my View, I have bound the source of the DataGrid to the `IProfiles` which is an `ObservableCollection` that stores instances of the `IProfileModel`. Each TextBox corresponds to one property of the `IProfileModel` class, thus the Text property of each TextBox is bound to its respective nested property of the `IProfile` property of the ViewModel. The "Add" Button is bound to the respective ICommand in the ViewModel called the `AddNewIProfileCommand`

In my ViewModel, I have added the `IProfileModel` as one of its properties using the name `IProfile`, the TextBox.Text properties are bound to the nested properties of the `IProfile` as shown in the XAML of the View. As for the `AddNewIProfileCommand`, I have made so that it corresponds to a private method called the AddNewIProfile() which will add a new `IProfileModel` object whose properties will refer to the nested properties of the `IProfile` property that is bound to the TextBoxes.

**Edit**:
I want to add that the `AddNewIProfile()` will add the new `IProfileModel` object to the `IProfiles` which is bound to the DataGrid

My main issue is that whenever I modified the TextBoxes and then clicked on the Button to add the profiles to the DataGrid, the newly added entry to the DataGrid is always a `IProfileModel` with empty property values (all string properties of the `IProfileModel` are null and all numerical type properties are 0). It seems like modifying the TextBoxes does not change the nested properties of the `IProfile` even though I have set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged` and the `Mode` to `Two Way` and the `IProfile` itself is of the `IProfileModel` class which has inherited from the `ObservableObject` class.

Lastly, I know that my question is quite similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46154975/wpf-mvvm-add-new-object-to-observablecollection-using-textboxes-and-icommand) but I have followed the suggestions there and tried to match their solution but I somehow can't get it to work.
Thanks!

**Edit**:
Added some before - after picture of the DataGrid after the "Add" Button is pressed:
[image]
[image]

**Edit**:
The ParameterTextbox Style which was the cause of the error as pointed out by Cédric Moers in the comments:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"
           x:Key="ParameterTextbox">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Border CornerRadius="5"
                            Background="White"
                            Width="180"
                            Height="35"
                            BorderThickness="3"
                            BorderBrush="#EAEAEA">
                        <Grid>
                            <Rectangle StrokeThickness="1"/>
                            <TextBox Margin="1"
                                     Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"
                                     BorderThickness="0"
                                     Background="Transparent"
                                     VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                     Padding="5"
                                     Foreground="Black"
                                     x:Name="SearchBox"/>

                            
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: if you put a breakpoint in AddNewIProfile, are the values of the IProfile you are copying from correct?

Comment: @CédricMoers the IProfile has empty properties (null for string type properties and 0 for the numerical types) so when the AddNewIProfile tries to add it to the IProfiles, it adds a new IProfileModel object that copies an empty IProfile, thus the new DataGrid entry is empty as well

Comment: @KevinAnggrek: Try to remove `Style="{StaticResource ParameterTextbox}"`. Or please provide a *minimal* reproducible sample of your issue.

Comment: @mm8 yup, that turns out to be the main cause, I have added the XAML of the style to the post if you are interested. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to replicate your problem but I had to remove the styles since you did not provide them. It works at my side, so perhaps the problem lies within the style?

[image]

Please delete your styles for the textboxes (ParameterTextbox) and see if it works then. If you can provide me with the source code for the style, I can take a look at it. Maybe you are overriding the text property.

**edit after it turned out the style was the issue**

here is an example of the style you want to accomplish in a minimalistic way.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="RoundedTextBoxCt">
        <Border 
            Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"                    
            Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"                                    
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"              
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"          
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"          
            x:Name="Bd" 
            CornerRadius="5">
            <ScrollViewer
                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"                        
                VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
    
    <Style x:Key="ParameterTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Width"                    Value="180"/>
        <Setter Property="Height"                   Value="35"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding"                  Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground"               Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush"              Value="#EAEAEA"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness"          Value="3"/>
        <Setter Property="Background"               Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource RoundedTextBoxCt}"/>
    </Style>
    
    ...
    
</UserControl.Resources>
```

I made the control template as a separate resource, this way 'rounded textbox' can be put inside of some 'shared' assembly, and you will be able to use it for other projects as well.

It is minimalistic, as in the minimal you'll need. If you want a full-fledged text box, copy the style from here and modify it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/textbox-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8
it might look scary, but most of the time it comes down to modifying only a few rules. Once you get the hang of it, it's quite easy.

Instead of working with the setters, and even a separate control template resource, you could hard-code everything within the control template, WITHIN the setter of the control template of the textbox style, but that's up to you.

Good luck!

[image]

Comment: btw, it's enough to only remove the ParameterTextbox style for only the Name property and see if this works. If the name pops up in the datagrid, the problem is within your style.

Comment: you are right! the problem lies within the style and it works after I removed the style. I set a TemplateBinding for the TextBox inside the style. Seems like the problem was there. I have added my style in the edit section of my post

Comment: @KevinAnggrek I made some edits for you as an example of how to get your template to work